# JDBC2: How do we ensure that the data access layer is isolated?

Tags: jdbc

I'm doing a school assignment and i have to put up a presentation notes of the question - "How do we ensure that the data access layer is isolated.". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 1. Only use JDBC code in the data access layer (and nowhere else). 2. Do not put "logic" code into the data access layer.

Comment: Thank you very much! But i don't quite understand what you mean, could you please explain in detail?

Comment: @Jieqin Check [this](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) article from BalusC, it is clearly mentioned about data access layer and how to go about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) website introduced by @Polppan clearly mentioned about data access layer and how to go about.